# dijit/form/Button onClick event

Tags: button, onclick, dojo

I am stuck..OnClick event is not firing.. What I missed?
Button created, I see it, but no event.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<script>

 require(["dijit/form/Button","dojo/domReady!"], function(Button){
   var b = new Button({value:"clickMe"});
    b.placeAt('btnDiv');
    var x=b.on("onClick", function(){alert('clicked'); });
  })

</script>
  <div id='btnDiv'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes. First, the event name only need to be used like,

`button.on("click", function() {...});` // **NOT** button.on("**onClick**", function() {...});

and then the second is that, the value is not taken for button widget. It is "label" attribute. So, try this way:-

```
require(["dijit/form/Button","dojo/domReady!"], function(Button){
  var b = new Button({label:"clickMe"});
  b.placeAt('btnDiv');
  var x=b.on("onClick", function(){alert('clicked'); });
})
```

No themes are being used, so the widget will be occupying just few pixels next to the normal HTML button which you would look on screen. If you try clicking there, if you are not going to use the label attribute. If you just make the above changes, you will see the label separately around the HTML button, which when cicked, the above function will be invoked.

How it looks without a theme?

[image]

I have added the red border and the arrow for highlighting here. You will see only that text. If that is clicked, then the event will invoke, not when the HTML button is clicked. Because, the event is attached to the widget, not to the HTML element. This is why applying a theme is important to avoid this confusion.

### Additional:

How to add a theme? - Just add these following css in beginning and add `class="claro"` to body tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
  @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
</style>
```

How it looks now with the theme:-
[image]

Check out this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/D5kLg/